Withholding of tax on nonresident aliens - US & Mauritius?
The Context:
Me: A Sole Trader with an opened business in Mauritius, currently located in Mauritius, never been to the US, constantly working remotely from Mauritius. (non US citizen)
Company Employer: Based in Europe, but the financial operations are in the US. The contract I am signing states that I am providing services for the EU, not the US.
I've been notified by a potential employer that there's a chance that if they transfer my salary directly into my Mauritian bank account, 30% will be taxed because there's no double tax agreement between the US and Mauritius. They also provided me with this link: TaxNotes Article.
I also found this link: IRS - Persons Employed Abroad by a US Person.
Seems like it's applicable to me.
It states:

As a general rule, wages earned by nonresident aliens for services
performed outside of the United States for any employer are foreign
source income and therefore are not subject to reporting and
withholding of U.S. federal income tax.

My Question:
Is this law truly applicable to me? I pay all of my taxes in Mauritius.
Thank you in advance for any insights or advice!


Is this law truly applicable to me? I pay all of my taxes in Mauritius.

This law doesn't apply to you because US laws don't apply to you. You're neither a US citizen, nor a US resident, nor physically present in the US. You're not under the US jurisdiction.
The law does apply to the company paying you since they are in fact a US company and under the US jurisdiction (you're being paid by the US entity of your EU employer, per your description).
That said, income subject to withholding has to be US-sourced income (see the note in the IRC Sec. 1441(a): "(to the extent that any of such items constitutes gross income from sources within the United States)"). Since you're performing personal services outside the US, your earnings are not a US-sourced income. They're not subject to withholding.

Thank you very much for answer!

And more to the point: there should be no US income tax on that income. There should be no withholding either, but if the company withheld some tax in error, the OP should be able to get it refunded on their tax return since they would owe no tax.

Yes, but that would be very messy. The OP will need to file a 1040NR after the end of the year, will wait for god knows how long for the refund, and will potentially get the money back more than a year after it was erroneously withheld. Ideally we'd want to avoid that situation, it's both expensive and inconvenient for the OP.

@littleadv I recently had a brief checkup call with my employer, during which they mentioned the possibility of filling out Form W-8BEN on their end. Could you please advise if this would still be acceptable, or if there is a significant risk that they will be required to pay a 30% tax due to the absence of a tax treaty between the US and Mauritius?

@Chewiex filling form W8-BEN is required before they can make any payments to you, regardless of withholding. If you had any tax treaty benefits to reduce the withholding you'd claim them on that form as well. In your case, since your income is not taxable in the US at all, there are no withholdings.

@littleadv Hi, sorry to bother you again. My employer still insists that there is a high chance that tax is applicable to my income from the US, citing this part:
"Foreign persons are subject to U.S. tax at a 30% rate on income they receive from U.S. sources that consists of services performed, etc"
But what I'm reading about "Foreign person" - A foreign person includes a nonresident alien individual and certain foreign entities that are not U.S. persons (entities that are beneficial owners should complete Form W-8BEN-E rather than this Form W-8BEN).
Which not related to me, right?

Your income is not from US sources, it's from Mauritius sources. Hire an attorney if your employer doesn't know what they're doing.
